# Saving multiple data frames from loop

Tags: python, loops, url

I have been searching for a solution to my problem, but all answers I find uses print() at the end of the answer, and NOT saving the data frames as I would like to.

Below I have a (almost) functioning code that prints 3 seperate tables. How do I save these three tables in 3 seperate data frames with the names matches_october, matches_november and matches_december?

The last line in my code is not working as I want it to work. I hope it is clear what I would like the code to do (Saving a data frame at the end of each of the 3 rounds in the loop)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url  = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_games-'
valid_pages = ['october','november','december']
end = '.html'
for i in valid_pages:
    url = '{}{}{}'.format(base_url, i, end)
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))
    print(df)
    matches + valid_pages = df[0]
```

Comment: What is the variable `matches` in your code?

Comment: You haven't defined matches, so this won't work. Add `matches = ''` to the start

Comment: Maybe that is what I misunderstand. "matches + valid_pages" is the name of the new data frames. matches is defined in the last line.

Comment: @Dennis.M That will not work.

Comment: @Jonas Typically, this is done with a dictionary. Would you be opposed to that? Access would look something like `dict_of_dfs['matches_october']`

Comment: @brentertainer - I would not be opposed to dictionaries. I am just not sure how to implement it?

Comment: I'd second @brentertainer's opionon: this is a case for dictionaries. If you insist on using separate variables you could use `exec(matches + valid_pages + ' = df[0]')`, but this would be frowned upon by the python community :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can case it, but that's not very robust (and it's rather ugly).

```
if i == 'october':
    matches_october = pd.read_html(str(table))
if i == 'november':
    # so on and so forth
```

A more elegant solution is to use a dictionary. Before the loop, declare `matches = {}`. Then, in each iteration:

```
matches[i] = pd.read_html(str(table))
```

Then you can access the October matches DataFrame via `matches['october']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compose variable names using `+`, try using a `dict` instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

matches = {} # create an empty dict

base_url  = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_games-'
valid_pages = ['october','november','december']
end = '.html'
for i in valid_pages:
    url = '{}{}{}'.format(base_url, i, end)
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))
    print(df)
    matches[i] = df[0]  # store it in the dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. That worked! :)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

matches = {} # create an empty dict

base_url  = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2019_games-'
valid_pages = ['october','november','december']
end = '.html'
for i in valid_pages:
    url = '{}{}{}'.format(base_url, i, end)
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0] 
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))
    matches[i] = df[0]  # store it in the dict

matches_october = matches['october']
```